# ASP.net digits always rendering as Latin regardless of culture

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization, multiple-languages

I'm trying to render integers in their native form.  I set the culture info as follows:

```
CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(ViewingLanguage.LanguageTag)
{
    NumberFormat = new NumberFormatInfo{DigitSubstitution = DigitShapes.NativeNational}
};
```

And have the function:

```
public static string NiceNumber(CultureInfo culture, int number)
{
    return number.ToString(culture);
}
```

Whatever the culture is set to `ar-QA`, `zh-HANS` etc, the digits always render in their latin form.

How do I render the digits in their native form?

Comment: Try setting CurrentUICulture.

Comment: try CreateSpecificCulture method

Answer (score 0):

This is the first thing I do in multilingual web apps.  It should work for you too.  Although note this [comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentexception?view=net-5.0) from MSDN:

The CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture method throws ArgumentException for the neutral cultures "zh-Hant" ("zh-CHT") and "zh-Hans" ("zh-CHS").

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    if (Request.QueryString["lang"] != null)
    {
        string m_selectedLanguage = Request.QueryString["lang"];
        UICulture = m_selectedLanguage;
        Culture = m_selectedLanguage;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(m_selectedLanguage);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(m_selectedLanguage);
    }

    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```